# Python: 'ModuleNotFoundError' when trying to import module from files

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path, python-import

i want to access *config/cache.py* from *test.py* And ,I need internal access like from *config/env.py* to *database/modules/game.py* but i get this error always:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

my project tree:

```
project
├─ modules
│  ├─ cache
│  │  ├─ playtime.py
│  │  └─ __init__.py
│  ├─ config
│  │  ├─ cache.py
│  │  ├─ database.py
│  │  ├─ env.py
│  │  ├─ yaml.py
│  │  └─ __init__.py
│  ├─ database
│  │  └─ models
│  │     ├─ game.py
│  │     ├─ member.py
│  │     ├─ room.py
│  │     ├─ wiki.py
│  │     └─ __init__.py
│  ├─ room
│  ├─ utils
│  │  ├─ functions.py
│  │  ├─ logger.py
│  │  └─ __init__.py
│  └─ __init__.py
├─ run.py
└─ test
   └─ test.py
```

and inits file are like that:

```
from .config import *
from .utils import *
from .database import *
from .cache import *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python automatically insert the folder in which the main script resides to `sys.path`, which is a list containing folders where to find packages and modules.

So, if `test.py` were in folder `project`, that folder would be in `sys.path` and then you could import the `modules` package and any of its subpackages or modules.

```
import module  # main package module
from module import config   # subpackage config
from module.config import env  # module env
```

(Just in case, a module is a file ending in .py, and a package is a folder with a file called `__init__.py` inside and optionally subpackages and/or modules.)

So one solution wood be to move the file test.py to `projects`

Another alternative is to add the folder `projects` (as a `str`) manually to `sys.path` which is a simple python `list` before importing.

```
import sys
sys.append('.../projects')
from modules.config import env
```